# How to dynamically change a XAML resource value for UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have a global double resource which I use for my UI to set the font size via "StaticResource" extension.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:Double x:Key="MyFontSize">20</x:Double>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and then I do:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource MyFontSize}" Text="Something"><TextBlock>
```

But I want this setting to be dynamic so that user can change it during runtime via settings on my application without restarting it. I heard there used to be "DynamicResource" extension in WPF which solves this. But that extension is not present in UWP.

So what is the way to do it in UWP?

Comment: bind to a static double property?  "{Binding Source="{x:Static local:MyUserSettings.FontSize}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has your `FontSize` property:

```
public class UserSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private double _fontSize = 20;
   public double FontSize
   {
       get { return _fontSize; }
       set { _fontSize = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
   }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now, during the app launch create an instance of this class and store it as a `Resource`:

```
Application.Current.Resources["UserSettings"] = new UserSettings();
```

And now use data-binding to bind the `FontSize` property of your desired `TextBlock`s:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Source={StaticResource UserSettings}}"
           Text="Something" />
```

In the app settings you can modify the value like this:

```
( ( UserSettings )Application.Current.Resources["UserSettings"] ).FontSize = newFontSize;
```

But remember that this comes at a performance penalty and it would be better to do this statically and require the user to reset the app. Even better - let use the system-wide font size settings, because if the user prefers larger fonts, she will probably want so across the board.

Comment: This really makes me wish WPF supported the concept of relative font sizes, kind of like HTML does.  Take the parent object's font size and multiply it by `x`.  I suppose it could be faked with an attached property, but  first-class support would be awesome.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I got to home.

And you are right that system wide font sizes should be used whenever possible. I use system wide font sizes in most areas of the app and allow user to change the font size in some parts of the app since the app is heavily reading based and I want the user to be comfortable doing long reading sessions.

Comment: That makes sense definitely. It should not be an issue then :-)